# Sort latest most viewed questions according to tags?

Tags: discussion, tags

There is no doubt that in any time interval (couple of months) there are a few tags gaining most viewed questions.

For example, it looks nowadays questions tagged [iphone](/questions/tagged/iphone), [ajax](/questions/tagged/ajax), and [java](/questions/tagged/java)  gain much more view that the others. Asking such questions gains most attentions and returns huge reputation. I'm curious is there any trick to find the current hot (most viewed) tags?

Comment: The **default ordering** when visiting [`/tags`](http://stackoverflow.com/tags) is by popularity.

Comment: The default ordering is 'most asked' in this week and I'm looking for 'most visited'.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/) for that purpose, for example with this [query](https://data.stackexchange.com/worldbuilding/query/771147):

```sql
select top 100 tagname
     , sum(cast(p.viewcount as bigint)) as [sum of views]
     , avg(cast(p.viewcount as bigint)) as [average of views]
from posts p
inner join posttags pt on pt.postid = p.id
inner join tags t on t.id = pt.tagid
where p.creationdate > dateadd(m, -1, getdate())
and p.posttypeid = 1
group by tagname
order by 2 desc
```

When run today on World Building you're result will be:

[image]